# Etherscan Transaction Action Info

Tags: etherscan

I'm trying to establish if it's possible to use the etherscan API to establish the `Transaction Action` information (e.g. Swap 1 Ether For 2 Yf-DAI). If not, how are they doing it? I had a look to see how I could do it with web3 but I can't see how I would do that either.

Specifically I want to fetch a list of transactions of ETH and ERC20 tokens so I have a ledger of all activity associated with an account which I can use to calculate ROI etc..

Comment: Did you get a solution? Apparently am on the same road.

Comment: @dennohpeter same here. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the *Transaction Action* for Uniswap V2 using the event logs. Here is the [SO answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/127206/73887) and here is a [code example](https://github.com/j2abro/UniswapV2-Sandwich-Attack-Detector/blob/master/src/agent.ts#L272).