# How Etherscan calculate Transaction actions?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, defi

I would like to know If anyone knows how Etherscan calculates the "Transaction actions".

For example:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc92284776f7e9976f32a3ec1d8654be6873d21ac16d808168c7afedbac56be79

The transaction actions:
[image]

How do they retrieve this info in a so clear manner? I know there are the transaction receipt's logs but on the logs of that tx there are 18 records, so how does Etherscan analyze those 18 logs in order to retrieve a so clear transaction action?

Comment: I'd use the contract addresses from the transaction to determine which protocol is being used and then interpret the events generated. That should be pretty easy for ES since they already have the code from registered contracts.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they have to manually code that for each protocol. I was able to recreate the *Transaction Action* for *Uniswap V2* in code by using the event logs and extracting the `swap()` and `transfer()` event attributes. The events were logged in order and the result was that the chain of trades for the pair, such as A->B->C->D, could then be consolidated to the net trade A->D, which matched Etherscan's results.

Here is [the code](https://github.com/j2abro/UniswapV2-Sandwich-Attack-Detector/blob/master/src/agent.ts#L272) that does from my [Uniswap V2 Sandwich Attack Agent](https://github.com/j2abro/UniswapV2-Sandwich-Attack-Detector) - while this runs on the Forta network, the same technique should be possible by capturing the logs elsewhere, i.e. Infuria.